# install windows 8 alongside ubuntu 12.04

Tags: grub2

I have 2 partition in my laptop and already installed ubuntu 12.04. My question is how can I install windows 8 without overiding my ubuntu grub. I searched over the forum and there are grub related problems after installing windows 8 alongside ubuntu. I really appreciate if you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not let you install on anything else than the 1st partition on a disc. A 2nd, 3rd partition will not be useable to install Windows on. It has to be the 1st partition of a disc.

> without overiding my ubuntu grub

Not going to happen; the fastest method to get a dual boot is to format your system, create 2 partitions, install Windows in the 1st and install Ubuntu in the 2nd. That will delete grub and recreate it during the installation of Ubuntu. 
Just make sure you backup all your data.

Alternative that is going to cost a LOT of time if the discs are not empty: resize your partition, create empty space at the beginning(!) so you can make it a partition to install Windows. But this will have you mess with grub yourself: you are moving Ubuntu from partition 1 to partition 2. The re-install is quicker but also less error prone.